# Blue line following my touch on the screen of Huawei devices

Tags: screen, huawei, touch

Sometimes strange 'worm' and 'dust cloud' starts to follow my finger when browsing with my Huawei Honor 7.

> [image]

When the finger is not touching the screen anymore, the line disappears.

I can also draw over the navigation buttons at the bottom of the screen.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It is Huawei's Knuckle Gestures.

From [Use Your Phone with Your Knuckles](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00710082),

> Knock the screen with a knuckle and hold it until a blue dot appears. You can then drag your knuckle [...]. As you move your knuckle, a blue line will appear on the screen [...].

Comment: Also, [here is Phandroid's YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLR03PazXBU) demonstrating the feature and [a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp8Iy.png).